# How to find the highest of 2 values in a dictionary where value is a list

Tags: python

```
emp_dict = {'Name1' : ['2','M','10',5,datetime.date(2002, 10, 10)],
            'Name2' : ['3','G','5',7,datetime.date(2003, 10, 10)],
            'Name3' : ['1','M','15',9,datetime.date(2004, 10, 10)],
            'Name4' : ['4','G','3',3,datetime.date(2010, 10, 10)],
            'Name5' : ['5','M','5',8,datetime.date(2006, 10, 10)]}
```

In my dictionary (emp_dict) values are list containing string, integer and date. Value list include

```
Index 0 - ID
Index 1 - Gender
Index 2 - Department
Index 3 - Rating
Index 4 - DoJ
```

In the value list with index 3 is the rating given to the employee which is the key. I want to sort the data based on employees with highest rating and print the top 2 employees details.

**Output**

```
Name3

ID         : 1
Gender     : M
Department : 15
Rating     : 9
DoJ        : (2004/10/10)

Name5

ID         : 5
Gender     : M
Department : 5
Rating     : 8
DoJ        : (2006/10/10)
```

Comment: If you only had to find *one* "top" rated entry in the dictionary, how would you do it then? That might be a good start.

Comment: i'd just use a dataframe for that

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
def sort_rating(data, limit=2):
    rating_list = [d[3] for d in data.values()]
    keys = list(data.keys())

    output = {}

    for i, rating in enumerate(sorted(rating_list, reverse=True)):
        if i == limit:
            break

        index = rating_list.index(rating)
        key = keys[index]
        output[key] = data[key]

    return output
```

try it

```
>>> emp_dict = {'Name1' : ['2','M','10',5,datetime.date(2002, 10, 10)], 'Name2' : ['3','G','5',7,datetime.date(2003, 10, 10)], 'Name3' : ['1','M','15',9,datetime.date(2004, 10, 10)], 'Name4' : ['4','G','3',3,datetime.date(2010, 10, 10)], 'Name5' : ['5','M','5',8,datetime.date(2006, 10, 10)]}
>>> sort_rating(emp_dict)
{'Name3': ['1', 'M', '15', 9, datetime.date(2004, 10, 10)], 'Name5': ['5', 'M', '5', 8, datetime.date(2006, 10, 10)]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really sort a dictionary, but you could do what you want by converting it to a list and then sorting. Something like `sorted_employees = sorted(emp_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[3])` should do the trick.
You can find extensive explanation about how this works over [here](https://realpython.com/sort-python-dictionary/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort then use

```
sorted(emp_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][3], reverse=True)[:2] # this will give you top 2 employess
```

Also if you just want the top 2 employee without sorting then you can use `max`

```
top_1 = max(emp_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][3])
top_2 = max(emp_dict.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1][3] and x!=top_1))
```